# How to Import a library in Atom Editor?

Tags: python, bash, atom-editor

I'm new to Atom Editor and I have tried importing libraries by just including "Import pygame" or "Import kivy" at the top of my code.

However when I run my code it makes an error messages saying that there are no such modules with that name.

What's the proper way to make the editor import a library or a framework?

Comment: You need to install them before you can import them in a script. What version of python is this?

Comment: How can I know if its installed? I used pip to install them on the command line but I'm not sure if they are installed or not? I have 2.7 and 3.6 both installed

Comment: I have a feeling you installed them for 1 version of python and are trying to use them with the other. Which version do you want to install them for?

Comment: I want the libraries to be installed for Python 3 and I also want to specify to the Editor that I'm using Python 3

Comment: I'm not familiar with using atom, so I can't help with that part. Have you added python 3 to your systems PATH variable?

Comment: I'm absolutely clueless when it comes to PATHs and the command line in general. can you kindly refer me to useful tutorials regarding that?

Comment: I may be a bit I'm on mobile right now. I was assuming your on Windows, sorry about that. Is that the case? I'm just trying to get enough info that I know where to direct you

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, I'm on OS X. i will look up general command line tutorials and hopefully i will be able to work with PATH

Comment: I have never used python on osx, so I can't do this off the top of my head. I'll try to find some tutorials that would help you when I get home. Too much work on my phone, sorry. If what I suspect is happen is the case, then you should be trying to find tutorials on using pip to install modules for specific python version on osx. I may be wrong about the issue, but this is what I suspect. If you still need help when I'm home I'll check

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! i'll be happy if you gave me the tutorials whenever you are free and can :)

Comment: Can you do `pip3 install pygame` in terminal?

Comment: I did and the terminal responded: Requirement already satisfied: pygame in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages

Comment: Can I add this at the top "Import /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python‌​3.6/site-packages"  or it doesn't work like that?

Answer (score 1):

No such modules error is related to Atom. Make sure that you have installed the necessary package in your virtual environment and run the application by activating the virtual environment.

Simply put, if you want to install Python packages, use the following the command in a terminal:

```
$ pip install <packages>
```

You can also read [this Documentation example](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/) on the subject.

Once they are installed, then you may import them in a Python script.

Comment: Thank you I'll look that up. Are there any tutorials regarding virtual environment you can refer me to?

Comment: @goldfrappp I hope this link might be useful for you. [link](http://python-guide-pt-br.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/)